# Read SSL certificate from browser using Java script

Tags: javascript, ssl, certificate, man-in-the-middle

I want to read the SSL certificate of the current page in a browser using javascript. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript?newreg=74dd38484eac4f9c88eed0433c4e9a1d) which was around 2010. But I want to know is there any now? I need this to prevent man in the middle attack using SSL pinning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get SSL certificate details using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript)

Comment: I have already added this duplicate in the question.
It was around 2010 . I want to know if there is way now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Within a web browser, is it possible for JavaScript to obtain information about the HTTPS Certificate being used for the current page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402121/within-a-web-browser-is-it-possible-for-javascript-to-obtain-information-about)